# What exactly does VBScript's RegExp function do and what is the javascript equivalent?

Tags: javascript, regex, vbscript

I'm converting something from VBScript to javascript which runs RegExp() on a textbox to check if it can be submitted and I wasn't sure exactly what it was doing.

Comment: Why don't you post the actual regular expression as well?

Comment: That was one of the problems. I wasn't sure what the VBScript RegExp was filtering for, either looking for bad letters or making sure it's only good letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which is used to check for patterns inside text. Most likely it's checking if the value inside the textbox is valid.

The JavaScript equivalent is also RegExp. [This website](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has good regular expression information ([for JavaScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html), for [VBScript](http://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html)). The syntax for the regular expression string itself is similar in both languages, but the syntax for creating and using a RegExp object is different.

Comment: Ah, wonderful, thank you. I was sure I tried that before, but then again it is still quite early

Answer (score 0):

They are quite similar, so you shouldn't have too much difficulty in porting the VBScript regex stuff to Javascript.
These two links should be helpful:

- [Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions in JavaScript](http://www.evolt.org/node/36435)

the javascript oriented article has the available methods at the bottom of the article (about a third of the way down the page).